# Unstable Haskell web client authentication code

Tags: haskell, curl

I've made this little program in Haskell to get an access token from social media site. The problem is that it doesn't work every time, say one of five, never from the first try. Instead of an access token it gets an unsolvable third form or enters infinite loop. I also got a Python program (robobrowser based) that works reliably. I'm new to this kind of programming so I have no idea what may be wrong.

```
import Network.Shpider
import Network.Curl
import Data.Map
import Text.Regex.Posix
import System.Directory

getAccessToken email pass url userAgent = runShpider $ do
   let extractForm = head . forms 
       confirmForm page input = 
         let theForm = extractForm page
         in  theForm { inputs = delete input (inputs theForm) }
       pattern = "access_token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" 
       token pattern page =
         let matrix = (source page) =~ pattern 
         in  matrix!!0!!1
   isCookieFile <- liftIO $ doesFileExist "cookies"
   when isCookieFile $ liftIO $ removeFile "cookies"
   addCurlOpts [CurlUserAgent userAgent, CurlFollowLocation True] 
   (_, page1) <- download url
   (_, page2) <- sendForm $ fillOutForm (extractForm page1) $ pairs $ do
     "email" =: email
     "pass"  =: pass
   (_, page3) <- sendForm $ confirmForm page2 "__CANCEL__"
   return $ token pattern page3
```

Comment: What have you done to try to debug it? One easy thing to do is throw print statements in there, printing inputs and outputs (just as you might do in pythin)

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I've run it using a modified version of the shpider library that printed inputs and outputs, I've used Fiddler web debugger to see the request headers and bodies as well the response headers. I can't figure out in what way is different from the python program that uses the requests package

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it using Session from wreq

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens hiding (element, elements, children)
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Text.Taggy.Lens
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as S
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as L
import Data.ByteString.Lazy 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Data.HashMap.Lazy
import Data.Maybe 
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Network.Wreq.Session as Session

getAccessToken email pass userAgent url = do 
     let opts = defaults & header "User-Agent" .~ [userAgent] 
     sess <- Session.newSession     
     page1 <- Session.getWith opts sess url
     let markup = L.decodeUtf8 $ page1 ^. responseBody
         actionUrl = T.unpack $ fromJust $ Prelude.head $ markup ^.. html . allNamed (only "form") . attributed (ix "id" . only "login_form") . attrs . at "action"
         extractedForm = markup ^.. html . allNamed (only "form") . attributed (ix "id" . only "login_form") . allNamed (only "input") . attrs 
         formParams = Prelude.map (\h -> case (h ! "name") of 
            "email"   -> S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "name") := (email :: ByteString)
            "pass"    -> S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "name") := (pass  :: ByteString)
            otherwise -> S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "name") := S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "value")) extractedForm 
     page2 <- Session.postWith opts sess actionUrl formParams
     let markup2 = L.decodeUtf8 $ page2 ^. responseBody
         actionUrl2 = "https://domain" ++ (T.unpack $ fromJust $ Prelude.head $ markup2 ^.. html . allNamed (only "form") . attrs . at "action")
         extractedForm2 = markup2 ^.. html . allNamed (only "form") . allNamed (only "input") . attrs  
         filterCancel = Prelude.filter (\h -> (h ! "name") /= "__CANCEL__") extractedForm2         
         confirmFormParams = Prelude.map (\h -> 
           if (member "value" h) then S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "name") := S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "value")
           else S.encodeUtf8 (h ! "name") := ("" :: ByteString)) filterCancel
     page3 <- Session.postWith opts sess actionUrl2 confirmFormParams 
     let pattern = "access_token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" :: String
         source =  B.unpack $ page3 ^. responseBody
         target = source =~ pattern :: [[String]]
     return $ target!!0!!1
```